# Python removing the strings in a list from a string

Tags: python

I have a big string and a big list of a stop words. I created a little example below.

```
s = "I am 20 years old. I live in New York in United States of America."
stop = ["am", "old", "in", "of"]
```

As you can imagine I want the members in stop out from s.
I tried this one.

```
for word in stop:
    s = s.replace(word,"")
```

I get this error.

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: That code works fine for me on Python 2.6. Are you _sure_ that the code in your question is _identical_ to the code that's giving you the error?

Comment: Did you really try that? It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following. Split the `s` to a list of words by . Then create a hash from the list of stop words. Then iterate through the list and if the value not in hash - leave it.

```
s = "I am 20 years old. I live in New York in United States of America."
stop = ["am", "old", "in", "of"]
arr = s.split(' ')
h = {i: 1 for i in stop}

result = []
for i in arr:
    if i not in h:
        result.append(i)

print ' '.join(result)
```

Comment: Using a `set` for the stop words is a little neater than using a `dict` (we don't call them hashes in Python). FWIW, a set is ultimately just a dict with Boolean values, but because it's a special type of dict it can have special syntax to make expressing set operations more natural.

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you. Indeed with set it is easier and looks better. Did not know that set is dict with boolean value. Thank you for teaching me something new :-)

Comment: @PM2Ring: I have used `set` in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26944653/1239189)

Comment: You can just remove the `: 1` in your dict comprehension to make it a set comprehension, too :-) (Or, well, use `h = set(stop)` or just make stop a set in the first place, of course)

Comment: @AliGajani: I saw that. And I meant to mention your excellent answer in my previous comment. But I think you're going a bit over the top with the unit test. :)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich thank you. I know that it is easy to change. I hope that this will help someone to learn in the same way I just learned from 2Ring's comment.

Comment: Well, I have a template in my PyCharm which I use for testing out things, and said, I'll just pop it in here. Of course, not the best test case :)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: I should slap you with a wet fish for suggesting `{i for i in stop}` :)

Comment: @PM2Ring: yeah, it was just a comment I often make when people have this kind of dict comprehension to simulate what a set does, after I made it I noticed that it would collapse to something as simple as that.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: No worries (and I hope you realise I was being playful). That syntax _does_ show the close relationship between dict and set. But it just should never be used in real code.

Comment: My first comment above is a bit wrong. I should have said: "A set is ultimately just a dict with keys but no values". Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

s is a list when you write s.replace(), so you probably made change to s, and it s now a list instead of a string

this code works well:

```
s = "I am 20 years old. I live in New York in United States of America."
stop = ["am", "old", "in", "of"]
for word in stop:
    s = s.replace(word,"")
```

try to find where you make modification of s, search for an assignment somewhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

#### Demo [here](http://ideone.com/YaaXsa)

The most elegant way would be to use [set difference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference).

```
z = list(set(string.split()) - set(stop))
```

This would print the following:

`['United', '20', 'I', 'live', 'years', 'States', 'America.', 'York', 'New', 'old.']`

**Unit Test**

```
import unittest

def so_26944574(string):
    stop = ["am", "old", "in", "of"]
    z = list(set(string.split()) - set(stop))
    return sorted(z)

# Unit Test
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def testcase(self):
        self.assertEqual(so_26944574("I am 20 years old. I live in New York in United States of America."), sorted(['United', '20', 'I', 'live', 'years', 'States', 'America.', 'York', 'New', 'old.']))
        self.assertEqual(so_26944574("I am very old but still strong, kind of"), sorted(['I', 'very', 'but', 'still', 'strong,', 'kind']))
unittest.main()
```

**Test Pass**

```
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to do this:

```
s = "I am 20 years old. I live in New York in United States of America."
stop = ["am", "old", "in", "of"]
s_list = s.split() # turn string into list
s = ' '.join([word for word in s_list if word not in stop]) # Make new string
>>> s
'I 20 years old. I live New York United States America.'
```